# Why separating syntax analysis from execution?

Tags: scheme, sicp

In SICP Chapter 4, the metacircular evaluator is modified by separating the syntax analysis from the execution, making the `eval` procedure look like:

```
(define (eval exp env)
    ((analyze exp) env))
```

and the book says that this will save work since `analyze` will be called once on an expression, while the execution procedure may be called many times.

My question is, how does this optimization work? It will work for recursive procedure calls, but how about other cases? The evaluator evaluates expressions one after another, `eval` will still be called on each expression even if they have identical forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to see several things: (a) the `analyze` function walks over each expression exactly once, (b) there is no code outside of `analyze` that scans the syntax, (c) the function that `analyze` returns does not call itself therefore running that function never leads to any further scanning of the syntax, (d) this is all unlike the usual evaluation functions where calling a function twice means that its syntax is scanned twice.

BTW, a much better name for `analyze` is `compile` -- it really does translate the input language (sexprs) to a target one (a function, acting as the machine code here).

Comment: Thanks for your answer first:)  Does this optimization only makes sense in cases of recursive calls? If I have a procedure `(define (loop) (loop))`, then `(loop)` won't be analyzed for each recursive call. But if I have two identical `if` forms then each of them will be analyzed when we call `eval` on them. Maybe I got something wrong when trying to understand this point.

Comment: It applies whenever a function is called more than once, saving on the scan that would have been done on the second call etc.  But these are of course not so important, it's only with recursive functions that the difference really makes sense.  But "only" is an understatement, since recursion is basically the same as looping -- no recursion is the same as no looping, and in such a world there's no point for compilation at all.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a compiler and a interpreter is that:

A compiler scan your source code only once and change it into to execution code (machine code maybe). When you execute your program the next time, you directly execute the execution code without analyzing the source code, which is efficient.

A interpreter, however, analyze the source code each time you execute your program.

**This optimization only makes sense in cases of your program will be executed more than once.**

As @Eli Barzilay said, "a much better name for `analyze` is `compile`", your analyzed functions is like the execution code. The recursive functions are like programs which would be executed more than once.

Answer (score 1):

`analyze` just does syntax analyses once and store the transformed `definition` and so on in the environment which may be used through `lookup-variable-value` directly when the related procedure is executed.

In contrast, the original metacircular evaluator twists the syntax analysis and execution which makes each execution invokes syntax analysis as well.

This link maybe helpful: 
http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~mairson/Courses/cs21b/Handouts/feeley-notes.pdf